# Script dies when trying to use $model->save()

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to use $model->save() .. but i can't get the error messages like the documentation instead the error message appears with trace error then the script dies.

for example i am trying to use this code:

```
$user = new Users();
$user->name = "Name";

if(!$user->save()){
   //do stuff if there is an error
}
```

the problem is that i always get the validation error like this and the script dies and never returns false to enter the if condition :

```
password is required
#0 ..../UsersController.php(106): Phalcon\Mvc\Model->save()
#1 [internal function]: ....\UsersController->createAction()
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->callActionMethod(Object(....\UsersController), 'createAction', Array)
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#5 ....\public\index.php(41): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#6 {main}**
```

Comment: what's the problem with this error message? go trace back the errors. at some point there is a `throw new Expception('password is required')`

Comment: You have somewhere in your code throwing an error on save.

Comment: the problem is not that error message, but i want to display the error message with a flash msg  like the documentation for example:
`if ($robot->save() === false) {
    echo "Umh, We can't store robots right now: \n";

    $messages = $robot->getMessages();

    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo $message, "\n";
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally found the solution, I found that somewhere in the services.php
this line was enabled and that what caused the exception to be thrown
`Phalcon\Mvc\Model::setup(['exceptionOnFailedSave' => true]` and after turning it to false,i can easily add my conditions and check the errors message using this code.

```
if ($model->save() === false) {
    $messages = $model->getMessages();
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo $message, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send flash error using

```
$this->flash->error("too bad! the form had errors");
$this->flash->success("yes!, everything went very smoothly");
$this->flash->notice("this a very important information");
$this->flash->warning("best check yo self, you're not looking too good.");
```

see documentation
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html